# Why the toggle is not working with other DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i have a fiddle link ! The problem is only 1st top div is working..

[http://jsfiddle.net/5Ux8L/4/][1]

HTML-

```
 <div id="top">top </div>
    <div id="box">box </div>
 <div id="top">top </div>
    <div id="box">box </div>
```

jQuery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#top").click(function (){
        $("#box").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique**

Comment: same IDs, use classes!

Comment: Can you write a code ?

Answer (score 3):

Use common class instead of ids, **you should not have duplicate ids**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".top").click(function (){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Alien, I overlooked.

Comment: Great, goes for +1 now :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have elements with the same id.  Change `top` from an `id` to a `class`.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="top">top </div>
 <div class="box">box </div>
 <div class="top">top </div>
 <div class="box">box </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".top").click(function (){
        $(this).next(".box").toggle();
    });
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5T3K2/

Answer (score 1):

Id of an element must be unique, so use class instead

```
<div class="top">top</div>
<div class="box">box</div>
<div class="top">top</div>
<div class="box">box</div>
```

then

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".top").click(function () {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2657X/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".top").click(function (){
    $(this).next(".box").toggle();
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ux8L/5/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use id name for multipal divs. Always use class. By the way here is your working code.

```
 <div class="top">top </div>
    <div class="box">box </div>
 <div class="top">top </div>
    <div class="box">box </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".top").click(function (){
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5Ux8L/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of Id . Id is  unique property. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncDRN/1/)

```
 <div class="top">top </div>
    <div class="box">box </div>
 <div class="top">top </div>
    <div class="box">box </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".top").click(function (){
        $(".box").toggle();
    });
});
```